# ¿Cómo cambiar del check a guión del checkbox de mi datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un checkbox en mi datatable en el `<thead>` para seleccionar todos los checkbox del `<tbody>` y lo que quiero es que al seleccionar todos los checkbox y luego al modificar un checkbox de las filas se ponga un guión en el checkbox del `<thead>` asi como el siguiente ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function crearTabla(datos) {
    let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
    let dt = $dt.DataTable({
      data: datos,
      order: false,
      columns: [{
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
            // ACA controlamos la propiedad para des/marcar el input
            return "<input type='checkbox'" + (full.checked ? ' checked' : '') + "/>";
          },
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Producto',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Cantidad',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Precio',
          orderable: false
        },
      ]
    });
    let $total = $('#total');

    // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
    $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function(evt) {
      let checked = this.checked;
      let total = 0;
      let data = [];

      dt.data().each(function(info) {
        // ACA cambiamos el valor de la propiedad
        info.checked = checked;
        // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
        if (info.checked) total += info.Precio;
        data.push(info);
      });

      dt.clear()
        .rows.add(data)
        .draw();
      $total.val(total);
    });

    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
      let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
      let total = parseFloat($total.val());
      // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
      info.checked = this.checked;
      let price = info.Precio;
      total += info.checked ? price : price * -1;
      $total.val(total);
    });
  }

  crearTabla([{
      "Producto": "Leche",
      "Cantidad": 50,
      "Precio": 3.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Azucar",
      "Cantidad": 40,
      "Precio": 2.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Gaseosa",
      "Cantidad": 14,
      "Precio": 6.50
    }
  ]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length="2" id="tbl-buys">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />
```

Comment: ¿Y porqué no tomas la parte del link del fiddle y lo acoplas a tu proyecto?

Comment: porque me parece que allí usa una librería y yo no estoy trabajando con esa.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta añadiendo qué librerías usas y qué usas para el código?

Comment: Las librerías están en el código mostrado para ejecutar y la data que llena el datatable también esta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poner la linea en el checkbox debes activar la propiedad "indeterminate"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function crearTabla(datos) {
    let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
    let dt = $dt.DataTable({
      data: datos,
      order: false,
      columns: [{
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
            // ACA controlamos la propiedad para des/marcar el input
            return "<input type='checkbox'" + (full.checked ? ' checked' : '') + "/>";
          },
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Producto',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Cantidad',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Precio',
          orderable: false
        },
      ]
    });
    let $total = $('#total');

    // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
    $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function(evt) {
      let checked = this.checked;
      let total = 0;
      let data = [];

      dt.data().each(function(info) {
        // ACA cambiamos el valor de la propiedad
        info.checked = checked;
        // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
        if (info.checked) total += info.Precio;
        data.push(info);
      });

      dt.clear()
        .rows.add(data)
        .draw();
      $total.val(total);
    });

    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
      let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
      let total = parseFloat($total.val());
      // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
      info.checked = this.checked;
      let price = info.Precio;
      total += info.checked ? price : price * -1;
      $total.val(total);

      /**  NUEVO CÓDIGO */
      /**  Verificar si todos están seleccionados */
      let countSelected = 0
      let countTotal = 0
      dt.data().each(function(info) {
        countTotal += 1;
        if (info.checked){
          countSelected +=1 ;
        }
      });

      /** Actualizamos UI según caso */
      if(countSelected===countTotal){
        $('thead input').prop("checked", true);
        $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", false);
      }else if(countSelected===0){
        $('thead input').prop("checked", false);
        $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", false);
      }else{
        $('thead input').prop("checked", false);
        $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", true);
      }
      /** END NUEVO CÓDIGO */

    });
  }

  crearTabla([{
      "Producto": "Leche",
      "Cantidad": 50,
      "Precio": 3.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Azucar",
      "Cantidad": 40,
      "Precio": 2.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Gaseosa",
      "Cantidad": 14,
      "Precio": 6.50
    }
  ]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length="2" id="tbl-buys">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />
```

Comment: Estimado @ivesklein por momentos deja de funcionar la propiedad indeterminate y deja de mostrarse y la única solución que hago es limpiar cache para que vuelva a funcionar y me resalta este código let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data(); con el siguiente error  jquery.dataTables.js:8109 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined

Comment: Deja de mostrarse porque la ejecución termina inesperadamente en el código que dices(info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()) todo lo que sigue no se ejecuta. Tienes que corregir la parte que calcula el total.